# Spotify API: Error parsing through JSON with Python

Tags: python, json, list, parsing, spotify

I have had trouble appending id's to a separate list as I parse through the JSON I receive from Spotify's "Users Saved Tracks" endpoint.

The JSON received looks like this:

```
    {
    "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks?offset=0&limit=20",
    "items": [
        {
            "added_at": "2021-11-16T13:56:51Z",
            "track": {
                "album": {
                    "album_type": "single",
                    "artists": [
                        {
                            "external_urls": {
                                "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/3iKDeO8yaOiWz7vkeljunk"
                            },
                            "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/3iKDeO8yaOiWz7vkeljunk",
                            "id": "3iKDeO8yaOiWz7vkeljunk",
                            "name": "Heavenward",
                            "type": "artist",
                            "uri": "spotify:artist:3iKDeO8yaOiWz7vkeljunk"
                        }
                    ],
                    "available_markets": [
                       
                ],
                "disc_number": 1,
                "duration_ms": 224838,
                "explicit": false,
                "external_ids": {
                    "isrc": "QZK6P2040977"
                },
                "external_urls": {
                    "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/track/6mJ1nbmQOm6iNClo71K5O6"
                },
                "href": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/6mJ1nbmQOm6iNClo71K5O6",
                "id": "6mJ1nbmQOm6iNClo71K5O6",
                "is_local": false,
                "name": "Hole",
                "popularity": 33,
                "preview_url": "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/c425dc91bdb19f1cddf2b35df08e30a03290c3c0?cid=8c9ee97b95854163a250399fda32d350",
                "track_number": 1,
                "type": "track",
                "uri": "spotify:track:6mJ1nbmQOm6iNClo71K5O6"
            }
        }
```

Right now my code that I am using to parse looks like this:

```
def getLikedTrackIds(session):

    url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks'
    payload = makeGetRequest(session, url)

    if payload == None:
        return None
    
    liked_tracks_ids = []
    for track in payload['items']:
        for attribute in track['track']:
            if (attribute == 'id'):
                app.logger.info(f"\n\nTrack ID: {attribute}")
                liked_tracks_ids.append(attribute)
    
    return liked_tracks_ids
```

My liked_track_ids is filled with the string "id", for each song:

```
[ "id", "id", "id", "id"....]
```

Can anyone provide insight as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, the json that i posted is only a short snippet of what I actually received. There are about 20 other "track"  json objects under the one i have in the question.

Comment: Your code literally has `if (attribute == 'id'):` followed by `liked_tracks_ids.append(attribute)` - so that's your answer right there. You probably wanted `liked_tracks_ids.append(track[attribute])` or just `liked_tracks_ids.append(track['id'])`

Comment: @Grismar is correct, although the solution would be `liked_tracks_ids.append(track['track']['id'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already commented under the question but your code can be simplified by getting rid of the loop:

```
def getLikedTrackIds(session):

    url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks'
    payload = makeGetRequest(session, url)

    if payload == None:
        return None
    
    liked_tracks_ids = []
    for track in payload['items']:
        liked_id =  track['track'].get('id', None)
        if liked_id:
            app.logger.info(f"\n\nTrack ID: {liked_id}")
            liked_tracks_ids.append(liked_id)
    
    return liked_tracks_ids
```